# Logic behind an IFF statement

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

If we have an iff statement such as: $A$ iff $B$, to show $A \Rightarrow B$ is it enough to show that

not $B \Rightarrow$ not A?

Comment: Yes; $A \to B$ and $\lnot B \to \lnot A$ are equivalent.